# filepulse source connector - value converter ssl schema registry configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

How can I provide value converter ssl schema registry configuration when I create filepulse S3 source connector? Does filepulse connector support ssl properties for schema registry?

I tried using the below configuration for creating filepulse S3 source connector

```bash
curl \
  -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
  -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/connectors/s3_source_connector/config \
-d '{
        "connector.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.FilePulseSourceConnector",
        "name": "s3_source_connector",
        "topic": "topicname",
        "tasks.max": 1,

        "fs.listing.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.AmazonS3FileSystemListing",
        "fs.listing.interval.ms": 10000,
        "fs.listing.filters": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.filter.RegexFileListFilter",
        "file.filter.regex.pattern": "test\\.csv",
        
        "fs.cleanup.policy.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.clean.LogCleanupPolicy",

        "aws.access.key.id":"key",
        "aws.secret.access.key":"secret",
        "aws.s3.bucket.name":"bucket",
        "aws.s3.region":"us-east-1",
        "aws.secret.session.token": "session_token",
        "aws.s3.bucket.prefix": "bucket",
        "tasks.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.AmazonS3RowFileInputReader",

        "skip.headers": "1",
        "offset.attributes.string": "uri",

        "tasks.file.status.storage.bootstrap.servers":"bootstrapserver",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.topic":"storage-topic",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.partitions":10,
        "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.replication.factor":1,
        "tasks.file.status.storage.topic.creation.enable": false,

        "filters":"CSVFilter",
        "filters.CSVFilter.type": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.CSVFilter",
        "filters.CSVFilter.extractColumnName": "headers",
        "filters.CSVFilter.trimColumn": "true",
        "filters.CSVFilter.separator": ",",

        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.security.protocol": "SSL",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.sasl.mechanism": "GSSAPI",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.key.password": "",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.keystore.location": "keystore.jks",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.keystore.password": "password",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.truststore.location": "truststore.jks",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.producer.ssl.truststore.password": "password",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.security.protocol": "SSL",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "GSSAPI",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.key.password": "",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.keystore.location": "keystore.jks",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.keystore.password": "password",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.truststore.location": "truststore.jks",
        "tasks.file.status.storage.consumer.ssl.truststore.password": "password",

        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "errors.log.enable": "true"

    }';
```

And I am getting the below exception

```
[2023-07-13 22:49:25,231] ERROR Error encountered in task jdbc_sink_connector_s3_src_connect-0. Executing stage 'VALUE_CONVERTER' with class 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter', where source record is = SourceRecord{sourcePartition={uri=s3://bucket-aws-useast1-apps-dev-1-dev/bucket/test.csv}, sourceOffset={position=132, rows=2, timestamp=1689288565168}} ConnectRecord{topic='topicname', kafkaPartition=null, key=null, keySchema=null, value=Struct{empName=John}, valueSchema=Schema{STRUCT}, timestamp=1689288565168, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=[ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.name, value=bucket/test.csv, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.uri, value=s3://bucket-aws-useast1-apps-dev-1-dev/bucket/test.csv, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.contentLength, value=132, schema=Schema{INT64}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.lastModified, value=1689275469000, schema=Schema{INT64}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.s3.object.summary.key, value=bucket/test.csv, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.s3.object.summary.etag, value=df96017ba0e96ddacd2de1736ade34eb, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.file.s3.object.summary.bucketName, value=bucket, schema=Schema{STRING}), ConnectHeader(key=connect.task.hostname, value=kafka-connect-s3sourceconn-79cdd7466f-fnjzw, schema=Schema{STRING})])}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to serialize Avro data from topic topicname :
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$3(WorkerSourceTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"ConnectDefault","namespace":"io.confluent.connect.avro","fields":[{"name":"empName","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:259)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:156)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:153)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:86)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:544)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:532)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:490)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:257)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:366)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:337)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:115)
    ... 17 more
```

I tried to add below schema key and value converters with schema registry url and keystore and truststore to the connector config. But i am getting the same error.

```json
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",

        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password": "password",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password": "password",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location": "truststore.jks",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "sehema-registry-url",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.key.password": "",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location": "keystore.jks",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: The connector class doesn't matter. Only the converter is throwing the exception, which is generic client error, not related to ssl... Can you please show server logs from the registry as well when this exception happened? Or, just load CSV data as strings, then use tools like ksqlDB to parse once in a topic